# What is this pinball machine that appeared in "The Children of Violent Rome"?

Tags: game-identification, pinball

This pinball machine appeared in the movie, *The Children of Violent Rome* (1976):

[image: screenshot of above-described pinball machine]

What is the model of this pinball machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both appear to be manufactured by Gottlieb. The right one is <s>King Ping</s> *Ten Up*.  <s>The only difference I can see is the film appears to maybe somehow altered out the words "King Pin" (or it could be present, just hard to see due to the grainy-ness of the image). You can see other features quite clearly though, like the bowling pins above the score, and some of the people.</s>

The left one appears to be *Space Orbit*.  The one in the movie appears to be quite identical, and you can somewhat make out the text of the game name.

Sources:

- [Space Orbit](https://www.ipdb.org/machine.cgi?id=2255)
- [Ten Up](https://www.ipdb.org/machine.cgi?id=2521)

Comment: Previously I thought it was King Pin, but then I found Ten Up, which looks identical.  Seems like pinball manufactures were lazy with their back glass designs and reused many features!